# How are categorical variables used when fitting a decision tree in scikit-learn?

Tags: categorical-data, cart, scikit-learn

I am used to R, in which you can use factor(variable) to indicate a categorical variable. However, in scikit-learn, trying to pass a variable of strings causes the DecisionTreeClassifier to give an error.

How are you supposed to use a categorical variable in scikit-learn? Is the only option for encoding a multi-class variable to use dummy variables?

Answer (score 3):

To encode categorical feature as a scipy.sparse matrix you can use the [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) class. Then call the `.toarray()` method on the result to convert it to an contiguous numpy array as the scikit-learn trees do not support sparse input yet.